# Custom linux kernel module: ".gnu.linkonce.this_module section size must match the kernel's built struct module size at run time"

Tags: kernel-modules

I'm trying to load a barebones Linux device driver module, but I keep getting hit with this in dmesg:

```
module dummydriver: .gnu.linkonce.this_module section size must match the kernel's built struct module size at run time
```

When trying to load the module, I receive this:

```
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module dummydriver.ko: Invalid module format
```

My kernel version matches the one I'm using to build the module as far as I can tell, I'm running Pop OS 22.04 and here's `uname -r`:

```
6.5.6-76060506-generic
```

- Driver code:

  ```c
  #include <linux/module.h>
  #include <linux/version.h>
  #include <linux/kernel.h>

  static int __init driver_init(void)
  {
      printk(KERN_INFO "bababooey :D");

      return 0;
  }

  static void __exit driver_exit(void)
  {
      printk(KERN_INFO "bababooey :(");
  }

  module_init(driver_init);
  module_exit(driver_exit);

  MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
  MODULE_AUTHOR("dude");
  MODULE_DESCRIPTION("driver");
  ```
- Makefile:

  ```make
  obj-m = dummydriver.o
  KVERSION = $(shell uname -r)
  all:
      make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(shell pwd) modules

  clean:
      make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(shell pwd) clean
  ```
- Make output:

  ```
  make -C /lib/modules/6.5.6-76060506-generic/build M=/home/david/Programming/dummydriver modules
  make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.6-76060506-generic'
    CC [M]  /home/david/Programming/dummydriver/dummydriver.o
    MODPOST /home/david/Programming/dummydriver/Module.symvers
    CC [M]  /home/david/Programming/dummydriver/dummydriver.mod.o
    LD [M]  /home/david/Programming/dummydriver/dummydriver.ko
  make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.6-76060506-generic'
  ```

I've signed the module, and I've even tried turning secure boot off, but I continue getting that initial error in dmesg. If anyone has advice I'd appreciate it.